# Mutate a column based on a condition and a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- tribble(~ `ProbandID`, ~ `Visit_Group`,
       "1", "V1-B",
       "4", "V2-A",
       "1", "V2-B",
       "2", "V1-A",
       "3", "V2-B",
       "2", "V2-A",
       "4", "V1-A",
       "3", "V1-B")
```

Basically, it is a standard pre-post test design, with participants being randomized to two arms, here "A" and "B" and have their measurements done at two visits (pre and post intervention), here V1 and V2.

I have concatenated them into a single `Visit_Group` column.

I would like to now have a column based on colour values such that any unique `ProbandID` gets a unique colour *only if it is part of `B` grouping* and all `A`s are universally assigned to some constant colour. Here, the same proband ID gets repeated twice, as two tests were taken, and I want them both to have the same colour to indicate that it is the same person.

```
#Expected output - all A's assigned to a constant colour - black 
# and all the participants in B get a unique colour which is the same across both the visits (`ProbandID` 1 is gold and 3 is green)

df_res <- tribble(~ `ProbandID`, ~ `Visit_Group`, ~ `colors`,
       "1", "V1-B", "gold",
       "4", "V2-A", "black",
       "1", "V2-B", "gold",
       "2", "V1-A", "black",
       "3", "V2-B", "green",
       "2", "V2-A", "black",
       "4", "V1-A", "black",
       "3", "V1-B", "green")
```

I came up with a rather inelegant answer and any suggestions/answers would be highly appreciated.

My inelegant solution:

```
# filter out Group B and add a column with desire colour vector
m <- df %>% 
  select(Group, Proband.ID) %>% 
  filter(Group Group == "B") %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(cols = col_vector[1:17]) 

#filter out group A
s <- t %>% 
  select(Group, Proband.ID) %>% 
  filter(Group == "A") %>% 
  unique() 

# make a list containing the colour vector from `m` data frame and add empty strings to the size of "A" Proband's
mm <- list(prob = c(m$cols, (rep("",length(s$Proband.ID)))))

# name the list by concatenating in order and use this list in pheatmap annotatioin
names(mm$prob) <- c(as.character(m$Proband.ID), as.character(s$Proband.ID))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a built-in color dataset or create a custom one for your case. I am using a custom one here to create `color_name`.

We can check the last character of `Visit_Group` using `endsWith`. We then use `match` and `unique` to create an unique index number for each `ProbandID` which is used to subset `color_name`. All the "A" values by default get 1st index which is "Black" color.

```
color_name <- c('Black', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green')

new_df <- df %>%
           mutate(color = color_name[ifelse(endsWith(Visit_Group, 'A'), 1, 
                          match(ProbandID, unique(ProbandID)) + 1)])
new_df
# ProbandID Visit_Group color
#  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
#1 1         V1-B        red  
#2 4         V2-A        Black
#3 1         V2-B        red  
#4 2         V1-A        Black
#5 3         V2-B        green
#6 2         V2-A        Black
#7 4         V1-A        Black
#8 3         V1-B        green
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this would work if I want a unique colour to every `ProbandID`, but that's not the case, I want unique colours only to those who are also in the "B" arm of `Visit_Group` and a standard, non-changing colours to everyone else in the "A" arm

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `tidyr::separate`. It can be done using `grepl` from `base` and conditional mutating; moreover, we need to match ids which are associated with the colors to get the right match and not simply matching with unique entries.

```r
library(dplyr)
```

```
color_id <- data.frame(id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                       color = c('Black', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green'),
                       stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- tribble(~ `ProbandID`, ~ `Visit_Group`,
              "1", "V1-B",
              "4", "V2-A",
              "1", "V2-B",
              "2", "V1-A",
              "3", "V2-B",
              "2", "V2-A",
              "4", "V1-A",
              "3", "V1-B")
```

```
df %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(grepl("A", Visit_Group, fixed = TRUE), 
                        color_id[1,2], 
                        color_id[match(ProbandID, color_id$id), 2]))
```

```
#>   ProbandID Visit_Group color 
#>   <chr>     <chr>       <chr> 
#> 1 1         V1-B        red   
#> 2 4         V2-A        Black 
#> 3 1         V2-B        red   
#> 4 2         V1-A        Black 
#> 5 3         V2-B        orange
#> 6 2         V2-A        Black 
#> 7 4         V1-A        Black 
#> 8 3         V1-B        orange
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mind going over the last line of your code? I understand that first we're checking if the grepl statement is met, if it is met then it gets assigned the first variable from color_name. How does the match statement work by taking elements from the vector?

Comment: I mimicked that part from Ronak's answer, which I just realized it's not correct. Now I have a dataframe instead of `color_name` vector which has colors and ids beside each other. In the updated answer, I first match the `ProbandID` with `color_id$id` to get the right row, and associated color is stored in the second column (that's why I have `color_id[match(ProbandID, color_id$id),` ***```2]```*** ). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, `separate` is not needed. However, which other part of my answer is not correct?

Comment: @RonakShah you should not match with unique ids, but rather with the sorted unique ids. Check the last row color for instance. 4th color in the vector (should go with the id == 3) is orange while you get green in the results.

Comment: No, in my example I want it to return green as result. In my `color_name` 1st index is black which is for "A" group and rest all index are incremented by 1. Hence, I have used `match` + 1. OP said it does not matter which color goes to which `ProbandID` as far as the same color goes for same `ProbandID`. There is no restriction that ID = 3 should be "orange" and ID = 4 should be "green".

Comment: @RonakShah well that's bad practice in my eyes by OP, but in that case, nothing wrong with your answer.